# How do I open with read-only mode while saving csv file?

Tags: c#, csv, filestream, streamwriter

In C#, my program creates *.csv file.
And append data to this file every 1ms.
While append data, when I open *.csv file, this error occurs
I JUST want to open "ONLY READ MODE" while append data in this file.

/* File create */

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(csvFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        dataArray[i] = data[i];
                    }
                }
            }
```

/* Data Update */

```
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(csvFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                {
                    sr.Write(csv_count++ + ",");
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        dataArray[i] = data[i].ToString();
                    }
                    sr.Write(string.Join(",", dataArray));
                }
            }
```

When I open this *.csv file, this message pop-up.
"System.IO.IOException: ''D:\data.csv' The file is not accessible to the process because it is in use by another process.'

Comment: I think typically you cannot access a file while it's open for writing. Note your first code says `FileShare.None`. I think you will have to do a open-write-close loop. so it can be read in the meantime. BTW, why not use the simpler methods like `File.AppendAllText`?

Comment: Why do you want to open the file with `FileShare.Read` if you expect to write to it?

Answer (score 0):

FileShare.Read / Allow to open file in read mode while is in use by another program.

- When update / FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, **FileShare.Read**
- When open / FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, **FileShare.Read**

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are reading and writing on a file simultaneously.
While you are reading a file, the file would be locked unless you open the stream with `FileShare.ReadWrite`.
Otherwise, the file would also be locked while you are writing on it.

Proper FileShare value is `FileShare.ReadWrite`.

Checkout MSDN document for details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=net-7.0